# BrowserMob Proxy - The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browsermob

I'm trying to use `BrowserMob Proxy` with `Selenium` in C#.

I've tried this solution here: 
http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2012/02/automating-web-performance-stats.html

And my code looks like this:

```
Server server = new Server(@"path_to\\browsermob-proxy.bat");
server.Start();
Client client = server.CreateProxy();
client.NewHar("test");

var seleniumProxy = new Proxy { HttpProxy = client.SeleniumProxy };
var profile = new FirefoxProfile();

profile.SetProxyPreferences(seleniumProxy);
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

It fails at the third line.

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

If you can post a more detailed stack trace, that would be useful, along with the remote host you're trying to connect to. In the meantime a few things to try are:

- Check the address you're requesting. It seems you're getting a 404 -- can you hit it through a browser without the proxy?
- Make sure browsermob-proxy.bat is installed at the path on line 1 (is it really in a subdirectory of the working directory called "path_to"?)
- Check your write permissions in the temp directory, which is %TEMP% or %TMP% on Windows. BMP writes temporary files there.
- Grab the latest source and build the .bat file. The instructions are on the [browsermob-proxy github page](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) at the bottom (under *Creating the batch files from source*).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because your Jetty service is not actually running, did you get a message from BrowserMob batch file saying it couldn't run?   In my case it was a situation where the port (by default is set to 8080) but I had something else listening on that port.  To fix this, you can pass an optional port number.

```
var server = new Server(@"C:\path\to\bin\browsermob-proxy.bat", 9090);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on python. When I had tried to get content of localhost:8080 I got 404 error. It turned out that my other application was using same 8080 port. So I found PID typing in cmd: `netstat -o -n -a | findstr :8080`. Then I just terminated process with this PID and browsermob gave me well HAR.